# Hide this div inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like hide a div with values inside from an item with a button,
how to do this

```html
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  <div>{{item.comment}}</div>
  <div id="button">show comment</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you mean - not displaying ` <div>{{item.comment}}</div>`  before `<div id="button">show comment</div>` is clicked? 
try to add `display` : boolean to your item object(s) and set false by default.
use `<div ng-show="item.display">{{item.comment}}</div>`
and add `ng-click` to a button and method to toggle display property of an item. That's it

Comment: based on what do you want to hide button & can you share your items list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <div ng-show="item.rendered">{{item.comment}}</div>
    <div ng-hide="item.rendered" ng-click="item.rendered = true">show comment</div>
    <div ng-show="item.rendered" ng-click="item.rendered = false">hide comment</div>
</div>
```

We make use of on-the-fly `rendered` attribute in your Item object (does not exist, but created within the `ng-repeat` and initialize it:

- with `false` value to hide it for the first time.

or

- with `true` value to show it for the first time.

But default it uses `false`

Comment: Why the downvote?  Just to know what it's wrong with this answer?

Comment: It's not me, I will choose your version, it's close than what i'm looking for

Comment: I'll just not use the div hide comment, cause it's useless on my app ^^

Answer (score 0):

Use [ngShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) and, at every [ngClick](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick), change an attribute(like `item.show` in the example) of your item.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', function($scope){

  $scope.items = [{name:'name01', comment:'comment01'}, {name:'name02', comment:'comment02'}];

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" >
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
    <div ng-show="item.show">{{item.comment}}</div>
    <div id="button" ng-click="item.show = !item.show;">show comment</div>
  </div>
</div>
```